# Iterate through a log file in Java. Pull files scanned

Tags: java, symantec

I currently have a log file(see bellow) that I need to iterate through and pull out a list of files that were scanned. Then by using that list of files copy the scanned files into a different directory.

So in this case, it would go through and pull 
c:\tools\baregrep.exe 
c:\tools\baretail.exe
etc etc

and then move them to a folder, say c:\folder\SafeFolder with the same file structure

I wish I had a sample of what the output was on a failed scan, but this will get me a good head start and I can probably figure the rest out

[Symantec Image of Log File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q280G.gif)

Thanks in advanced, I really appreciate any help that you can lend me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. Now, just adapt for your solution!

```
public static void find(String logPath, String safeFolder) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(logPath));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'[a-zA-Z]:\\\\.+?'");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
        }
        if (matcher.find()) {
            files.add(new File(matcher.group()));
            System.out.println("Got a new file! " + files.get(files.size() - 1));
        }
    }

    for (File f : files) {
        // Make sure we get a file indeed
        if (f.exists()) {
            if (!f.renameTo(new File(safeFolder, f.getName()))) {
                System.err.println("Unable to move file! " + f);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("I got a wrong file! " + f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it will work. However, where would I put where you pull from After "Processing file '" and before the next "'." to just get the file path outputted

Comment: Any one have any input?

Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: I didn't understand your question, can you try again and explain a little more?

Comment: When I run this Java, it is not outputting anything. I need it to scan the log file and export the list of files that are in it to a text file. 

So it would take this:
15:29:17.696931 [_1126]|Processing file 'C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\File8.exe'.

And turn it into 
C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\File8.exe

Comment: Well, if you read your question, you would see that you asked for a file move =\ Thats what that `f.renameTo` does, attemps to move a file. If you do not want to do that, then change the code to something else, or you have no knowledge in Java? Can you change the code to do what you want?

Comment: Pretty new to Java. I guess my problem is that the matcher isn't catching anything therefore the files aren't getting moved.

Comment: Well, it should print "Got a new file! " and the file path. If it isn't, then the regex doesn't match. It should match. I don't know what is hapenning. Maybe the file isn't being parsed, try debugging in Netbeans or Eclipse for more info and tell me the results.

Comment: It appears that it is finding the files, but when it goes to do the f.exists()){ it is coming back as false

Comment: It is not finding it because there is the single quotes still associated with the path(ie. it's trying to find f = 'c:\asdf\asdf\asdf'.)

Comment: I'm not very experienced with regular expressions. It's returning the right values, but how do I strip the quotes? If I just delete them in the reg expression it returns the first letter of all the files and not the complete path

Comment: It needs to find "Processing file ' ", but only copy over the c:\a\a\a  without quotes. 

Thanks again for your help. appreciate it

Comment: `String s = matcher.group();` `s = s.substring(1, s.lenght()-1);` `files.add(new File(s));`

Comment: One last thing I promise. lol How can I keep the file structure on the move?

Comment: You cannot with this simple apprach, because this algorithm I wrote for you ignores this. What you must do is to first parse the directory being analyzied (AddSingleScanDirectory etc...) and store this. And then, when you move to the new folder, you must reconstruct this path by using the safeFolder you want to move, and then subtract the original folder from the filepath so you can have the relative folder structure. You should try to do this in a language you know, and not in a language you have no idea =\

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

This question is tagged as Java, and as much as I love Java, this problem is something that would be easier and quicker to solve in a language such as Perl (so if you only want the end result and do not need to run in a particular environment then you may wish to use a scripting language instead).

Not a working implementation, but code along the lines of the below is all it would take in perl: (Syntax untested and likely broken as is, only serves as a guideline.. been awhile since I wrote any perl).

```
use File::Copy;
my $outdir = "c:/out/";
while(<>)
{
  my ($path) = /Processing File\s+\'([^\']+)\'/;
  my ($file) = $path =~ /(.*\\)+([^\\]+)/;
  if (($file) && (-e $path))
  {
    copy($path,$outdir . $file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Note what he's got going on in lines 5 and 6.  You could do that in straight Java with RegEx.  He's got it reading line by line and is using regex grouping to pull out the specific filename which he passes on to copy.  Don't want to do this in Java and you may fear Perl (I do)...give groovy a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Its straight forward.

1. Read the Log file line by line using NEW_LINE as your deliminator. If this is a small file, feel free to load it & process it via String.split("\n") or StringTokenizer
2. As you loop each line, you need to do a simple test to detect if that string contains 'Processing File '.
3. If it does, using Regular Expression (harder) or simple parsing to capture the file names. It should be within the ['], so detect the first occurrence of ['], and detect the second, and get the string in between.
4. If your string is valid (you may test using java.io.File) or existing, you could copy the file name to another file. I would not advise you against copying it in java for memory restrictions for starters.
5. Instead, copy the string of files to form a batch file to copy them at once using the OS Script like Windows BAT or Bash Script, eg cp 'filename_from' 'copy_to_dir'

Let me know of you need a working example

regards

Comment: A working example would be great if it's not too big of a pain.